# Diff between two HTML chunks: structural instead of lines/chars?

Tags: javascript, html, diff

I'm looking for a JavaScript diff engine that will return the difference in the structure of two chunks of HTML.  That is, instead of, "at this line, at such and such character, something happened", it'd be, "this element was inserted after this element", or "this element was removed", or "this text node was altered", etc.

Cursory research suggests *this is hard*.

The specific scenario is that I have a live preview of Markdown text editor.  It works well with just text, but as soon as a user posts in, say, a YouTube `<iframe>` embed, then it renders/reloads on every keystroke, which is absurdly expensive.  Large images are difficult, too, because they cause a nauseous jittering effect as they load from the cache (at least in WebKit).

What would be beautiful is a replacement for `jQuery.html()` that instead of just replacing the HTML contents actually compared the old with the new, and selectively updated/inserted/appended so that unchanged elements are left alone.

Comment: Here’s something in Python: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/datadiff/

Comment: I would suspect it's [both] simpler [and arguably better overall] to just not use `html()`, but rather use proper DOM manipulation...

Comment: Well, so I have the HTML in the preview pane.  And then when the user changes the Markdown in the editor, Showdown.js returns the new HTML.  I don't know specifically what modifications occurred, which is precisely why I want a structural diff — so I can manipulate the DOM instead of replacing the entire preview.  Right?

Comment: (that's what I mean by, "a replacement for jQuery.html() that instead of just replacing the HTML contents actually compared the old with the new, and selectively updated/inserted/appended so that unchanged elements are left alone.")

Answer (score 1):

1. Deep clone (via `node.cloneNode(true)`) both nodes if they're currently in use (i.e. if any child nodes are referenced in your JavaScript).
2. Normalize both nodes via `node.normalize()`.
3. Iterate over every child node of both nodes and compare with `node.isEqualNode(other_node)`.
4. For every non-equal node, iterate deeper to see if you can find any equal child nodes.

To be honest, you're much better off using a text diff lib instead of making your own DOM-based diff lib.

Comment: Is there a strategy for when a new node is inserted randomly into the tree?  Or, say a user pastes in several paragraphs of Markdown text at once — or deletes a large block? Trying to match up nodes without getting mixed up by insertions/deletions seems to be the most difficult part.  (I did not know about `node.normalize()`, though -- should help quite a bit.)

Comment: You could try to apply my general algorithm in a way that text diff algorithms do it. I don't recommend you actually make a DOM diff lib.